# What, in summary, are we supposed to do to clean up tags?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, retag-request

I know it's not a good question title...

I'd like to have a question and short answer here on meta.SF that explains what - if anything - people can or should do to clean up tags.  I've seen blog posts about tag synonyms and wikis and I've seen Q&A here about cleaning up certain tags, but I've never seen a fairly short guide to "what should a normal user do to help clean up?"

A recent question related to HP-UX and I noticed that both hp-ux and hpux tags were in use on various questions.  hp-ux was more common and is more correct, so I changed all the hpux tags to hp-ux and edited many of the questions to read hp-ux instead of hp ux or hp/ux.

I'm wondering:

- was it worth doing this or if it would've been better to just post here and let a mod do it in bulk?
- how does a person set up a tag synonym?

Answer (score 4):

> was it worth doing this or if it
>   would've been better to just post here
>   and let a mod do it in bulk?

Yes, it was worth doing, but only if there are a few of them. If there are lots (I'd say, > 20) then don't bother, we don't want all those questions bumped to the front page. Post a question here on Meta and we'll take care of it.  What I also suggest you also do is suggest a synonym as well, which comes to the next question:

> how does a person set up a tag
>   synonym?

There's an (un-finished) question on MSO here: [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work)

Comment: It would be nice if questions didn't get bumped for only tag changes.

Comment: Don't both with tag synonyms, just request them on mSF. Nobody has the necessary prerequisites, the system was made for SO, it doesn't work for any of the other SE sites.